# List has no rows error in test class salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx

I have query `SELECT Body FROM Document WHERE Name = :Name`. It is giving List has no rows for assignment when i change the api version to 45.0.

Comment: From where are you running the query? Does it run under a different API version, and if so, which one? Are you certain that there is a Document record by the Name in the `Name` variable?

Comment: Yes. I queried same in developer console and document is available.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in test setup (preparation for the test run).

> Yes. I queried same in developer console and document is available.

From Developer Console it sees all data in your organization. However, for the test class you need to insert Document in TestSetup or set annotation for the test class `(SeeAllData=true)`.